# How to get distinct results in one row from two column of same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Let me clear first if heading is not sufficient.

I have a table like -

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `senderid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And sample data -

```
id  senderid  recid  
1   1         2      
2   1         3      
3   3         1      
4   6         1      
5   4         1      
6   4         2      
7   2         4
```

Now I want to know all transaction of senderid 1 to recid and from recid 1 to senderid like -
**EDIT**
I have made this -

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(recid SEPARATOR ', ') AS trans 
FROM test 
WHERE senderid =1 
UNION 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(senderid SEPARATOR ', ') AS trans 
FROM test 
WHERE recid =1 
GROUP BY recid;
```

And result is -

```
trans 
2, 3 
3, 6, 4
```

Which is in two row how i can combine both with distinct values
is it possible to achieve such using sql?

Thank you.

Comment: Your sample results do not make sense to me based on the data.  Can you describe how these results should be calculated?

Comment: Please check the question, I have made changes according to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with a bit of logic:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT((case when senderid = 1 then recid else senderid end) SEPARATOR ', '
                   ) AS trans 
FROM test 
WHERE senderid = 1 or recid = 1 ;
```

Comment: It totally worked, Now i can proceed.
I also used Distinct after group_concat to remove duplicate result. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  senderid,
  recid,
  IF(senderid =1, "senderid","recid") as transaction
FROM test 
WHERE 1 IN (senderid,recid)
```

Comment: please check I have edited my question with output required.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `union all` to get your desired result.the first query will return all transaction which has senderid=1,the second query will return rows for recid=1 then combine using union all to get all transactions

```
select * from test where senderid=1
union all
select * from test where recid =1
```

Comment: please check I have edited my question with output required.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one:

```
select distinct recid from test where senderid=1
union
select distinct senderid from test where recid =1
```

You should use `union` instead of `union all` because it reduces all duplication. I hope this will help.